# Wicket - redirecting to the same page when browser back button is clicked

Tags: java, browser, web-applications, wicket, back-button

I have a web application that uses the Wicket framework. It has a form that takes user input and when submitted, redirects to another page. Once the form is submitted and the browser's back button is clicked, the previous form is retrieved from the cache with the values entered. I need to override this behavior and redirect to the latter page (keep staying on the same page) when the browser back button is pressed. Is this possible in Wicket? If so, please guide me on how to achieve this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wicket handles URLs so if a previous page is requested by it's recognized by page ID that is by default added to the URL, e.g. http:/dummyexample.com?1

What I use to solve that problem is a flow engine that holds the state of model object within it. E.g. you have a model object of type MyFlow containing a field 'String currentState'. In this case if you required a wrong page, that is not belong the stage where your flow is, you can redirect to the relevant page from a controcutor or onIntialize() throwing 'RestartResponseException' that causes redirect to the new page.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Martin. But the form and its data are serialized before redirecting to the next page, and when the browser back button is clicked, Wicket deserializes and retrieves the same form. Therefore the constructor or onInitialize() won't be called. How can I check the current state in this condition?

Comment: You are right about the serialization. Anyway I've already solved a similar situation. I'll answer later, I don't have that project here to see my real solution and share it. But I guess I have added a flow hash into URLs and there is a map in the user session, where I look for the last state of the object to prevent the serialization problem.

Comment: Improving upon Martin's answer, instead of throwing 'RestartResponseException' within the constructor or onInitialize(), throwing it inside onBeforeRender() gets the job done. onBeforeRender() is guaranteed to be called when the page is newly constructed as well as deserialized.

Comment: @kasper360 you are right, I thought onConfigure(), but onBeforeRender() is much more suitable as you've correctly mentioned.

Comment: Actually `onConfigure()` is better because it is called on every render of a Component. `onBeforeRender()` is not called for invisible components. In the current case it doesn't matter because you talk about a Page, but have it in mind for non-Page components.

Answer (score 0):

Just use an Ajax submit, this way the user cannot return to the input form via back-button.

Comment: I am already using an AjaxSubmitLink to submit the data. But still this doesn't solve the problem.